Github Actions: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
Im currently trying to do a git diff between my feature branch and main branch in my github action but I keep receiving the same error around an ambiguous argument. It previously worked but now it throws this error.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Below is the Github action step causing this error:
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Detect Spec File
      id: spec-file-changes
      run: |
        array=()
        git diff --name-only main HEAD >> changed_files.txt
        grep -iE  'provider-apis/spec-files/rest/*/.*\.(json|yml|yaml)' changed_files.txt >> specpath.txt
        while IFS= read -r line; do
            array+=("$line")
        done < "specpath.txt"
        echo "paths=$(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -cs )" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

I've tried using just origin/main..HEAD as an alternative, but that doesn't work as well. I also tried refs/origin/main and that didnt work either.
Not sure what I'm missing here.

actions/checkout action takes a fetch-depth argument to fetch the entire git history instead of performing a shallow clone as the documentation mentions:
# Number of commits to fetch. 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags.
# Default: 1
fetch-depth: ''

You can try the following:
steps:
  - name: Checkout Repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0 # you can use 2 for example to only fetch the latest 2 commits
  - name: Detect Spec File
    id: spec-file-changes
    run: |
      array=()
      git diff --name-only origin/main HEAD >> changed_files.txt
      grep -iE  'provider-apis/spec-files/rest/*/.*\.(json|yml|yaml)' changed_files.txt >> specpath.txt
      while IFS= read -r line; do
          array+=("$line")
      done < "specpath.txt"
      echo "paths=$(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -cs )" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

Note that I changed the following line to use origin/main:
git diff --name-only origin/main HEAD >> changed_files.txt

